# CSV through API - Can only concatenate str

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, python-requests

I am running a CSV through a function I created and I keep getting the same error that reads `"TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str"`.

My hope is to have a final output that shows a CSV with the added values I am attempting to write to it. Right around where I write some values is where I see the error.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
import urllib.parse
import pandas as pd
import csv
import io

file_csv = "data_test.csv"

def get_data(item):
    domain_1 = "domain1.com" #@param {type:"string"}
    domain_2 = "domain2.com" #@param {type:"string"}

    domain_list = [domain_1,domain_2]

    query_base =  "https://api.semrush.com/?type=domain_organic&key=[API_KEY]&display_limit=1&export_columns=Ph,Po,Nq,Cp,Ur&display_sort=tr_desc&database=us"
    query_base_list = []

    for d in domain_list:
        builder = ""
        if d == "":
          continue
        else:
          builder += query_base
          if len(d.split(".")) == 3:
            builder += "&domain=" + d.split(".")[1]+"."+d.split(".")[2]
            builder += "&display_filter=%2B%7CUr%7CCo%7C" + d.split(".")[0] + "."
          else:
            builder += "&domain="+d
          query_base_list.append((d,builder))
    
    query_list = csv.reader(list(item))

    with open('output.csv','w') as f:
      f.write("Domain,Query,Ranking,Search Volume,CPC,URL\n")
      for d,r in query_base_list:
        for q in query_list:
          kw = urllib.parse.quote_plus(str(q))
          req = ""
          if len(d.split(".")) == 3:
            req = r + "%7C%2B%7CPh%7CEq%7C"+kw
          else:
            req = r + "&display_filter=%2B%7CPh%7CEq%7C"+kw
          response = requests.get(req)
          response_rows = response.text.split('\n')
          if len(response_rows) < 3:
            f.write(d + "," + q + ",101")  ## ERROR HERE
            kwdatacall = "https://api.semrush.com/?type=phrase_this&key=[API_KEY]&export_columns=Nq,Cp&database=us&phrase="+kw
            response = requests.get(kwdatacall)
            response_rows = response.text.split('\n')
            f.write(response_rows[1].replace(";",",")+",dnr\n")
          else:
            f.write(d + "," + response_rows[1].replace(";",",")+"\n")

    df = pd.read_csv('output.csv',sep=',')

get_data(file_csv)
```

Is there an easy way to resolve this? All help is appreciated!

Comment: Which line is giving the error?

Comment: The line that reads f.write(d + "," + q + ",101") @PaulinaKhew

Comment: Try to print d and q and their types before the f.write. Seems that one of them is a list. Although I couldn't spot an indication for that.